# How to fetch Email addres of an author via ID?

Tags: search, email, id

I want to make an HTML form which will have an input field to fill in the ID of the user. Then I want to pass the value into a php code such that the email address associated with that user ID is displayed. However, I am new to WP and don't know how to do it correctly.

I made a new php file in the root folder of my WP directory and put in this code and tried by browsing the file, but it didn't work.

```
<?php
$field = 53;
$value = 53;
function get_user_by( $field, $value ) {
$userdata = WP_User::get_data_by( $field, $value );

if ( ! $userdata ) {
    return false;
}

$user = new WP_User;
$user->init( $userdata );

var_dump($user);
}
?>
```

I searched in the web as well, but couldn't find anything of this sort? Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: "I made a new php file in the root folder of my WP directory and put in this code" - why did you redeclare or manually define the [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) function? Does your form submit to that PHP file (e.g. `<form action="https://example.com/some-file.php">`)? If so, then you shouldn't do that. Instead, use hooks like `admin_post_` (e.g. [`admin_post_action-name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_action/) for logged-in users) or `template_redirect` to properly handle form submissions in WordPress.

Comment: This didn't help. Can you explain a bit more. I am totally a beginner.

Comment: I was just saying, your form should *not* submit to a static PHP file outside of WP environment - if you had to manually load core WP files, then you're basically outside the WP environment. So perhaps you can try creating a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) and put your form code there (e.g. `<form method="post" action="">your form fields</form>`), and then you can test the `get_user_by()` function, e.g. add `var_dump( get_user_by( 'id', 53 ) );` somewhere in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_userdata()` to get a user object, and the email address will be the `email` property:

```
$userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );

if ( ! $userdata ) {
    return false;
}

echo $userdata->email;
```

Comment: I made a .php file in the root directory and pasted this code inside it, replaced ``$user_id`` with a valid user id of an user. When I ran the file, it echoed nothing.  What went wrong?

Comment: The code needs to go in a plugin or theme.

Comment: Try to paste the above code into functions.php(under activated theme), or create your own plugin.

Comment: When I kept this code inside the theme directory and tried running it with a valid user id, it showed a blank page. Why is it so?

Comment: You can't just put a file in the theme directory and run it. You need to make sure the code is loaded by functions.php and add it to a hook, or create a shortcode or something.